# How do I find specific elements to use to scrape data when using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am learning Python and Selenium, and I am trying to scrape information from a webpage (https://bluelighttickets.co.uk/event/all). I want to scrape information for each event listed on each page of the website.

I want to get the following:

- name of the event
- date
- location
- description

I will run the script daily automatically so that I can just check when anything new has been added.

So far I've made a script that opens the webpage and clicks through to the different event pages. However I am unable to extract the data that I need.
 My problem is that when I inspect each of the elements that I want, they are very specific, and therefore won't work for other events.
For example;
 I hoped it might say `date` or `location` in the element, but instead it says `23rd March` or `London`.
If I use those elements to scrape the data, then it will only scrape for that one event, and won't work for all events.
The description of the event has a class of `event summary` so I can use that, but for the `name`, `date` and `location`, I can't find anything that I could use to capture all events.
Am I missing something?

Comment: If there's no ID or class you can use, you just have to figure out the position of the DIV in the HTML and use indexing.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.